# How do I convert a survey scale [7-point, -3 to 3] to a 7-point scale [1-7]?

Tags: survey, scales, percentage, survey-weights

I am working with a survey scale that is from -3 to 3. I have a mean value of .94 and I want to identify if there are ceiling effects, but I need to change the entire scale to 1-7 in order to understand what the effects are (which I want to do by taking the mean value and dividing it by the total score possible score).

But I'm guessing I can't just do .94/3 because in reality, it's a 7 point scale and not a 3 point scale (for example, what would happen if the mean was negative?).

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not just add four?